# TSQL - Resolve a Deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, deadlock

I have a SQL Server Agent job that randomly hangs up (executes a stored procedure).

This time before the process was killed, I ran `sp_who2` and noticed multiple records with same SPID (1 = Running and all others = Suspended). It's due to parallelism. But this process was taking MUCH longer than usual. The CPU time was quite big. The process was killed but I feel like there was a deadlock issue (believe this was the cause the last time it was investigated). The query is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO trg.TargetTable WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
            (Col1, Col2, Col3...  )
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ...
    FROM src.SourceTable1
    JOIN src.sourcetable2 ON ...   
    OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Would this cause a deadlock (tablock/holdlock running in parallel)? If so, why does it happen randomly? Is it only when process goes parallel? And, how do I resolve it?

Update: Here's what I'm seeing from `sp_who2`'s output

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other statements that lock this table?  Is this in a Transaction with other statements.  Is there a trigger hiding locks on other tables?  I've never seen a single statement be able to deadlock with another instance of itself.  Also, deadlocks get auto-resolved by arbitrarily terminating one or more queries, and usually would have zero cpu associated with them, as all the deadlocked processes are waiting on each other.

Comment: There shouldn't be any other statement running when this job is executed (early AM) that would lock the target table. The statement is NOT wrapped in a traction either and no triggers.

It's strange because the process has been running for hours and would run longer if it wasn't noticed. This happens randomly only when the data is being inserted into this table (many more inserts run on different tables, but they don't have this issue and it's usually ok for this table as well).

Comment: A deadlock will not hang a query, deadlocks are detected very quickly and one process killed. So you case sounds very unlike a deadlock. Maybe more an out of resources issue. Deadlocks are stored in the health monitoring tables, so you can query them to find out if you really had one. Definitely don't start trying to solve a deadlock you're not even sure is a deadlock. And as MatBailie says, 2 processes are required for a deadlock, because locks (which result in deadlocks) are at the process level.

Comment: Would you know how to query deadlock history (or point me to a resource) - a quick search indicates I need to either run profiler or pre-config ext events (I did neither before killing this process). It might be resource, but what's strange is that the process randomly hangs only when it's processing this table.